# Calculate average number of days grouped by a month in R

Tags: r, date

i have a df with id's and dates for each id. I want calculate the average of the days per month for all the id's. For example an id has used worked the same day several times so this counts for one day, next day he worked also several times, so this count for one more day of work. I mean that for every id in the df  the same date appears a lot of times because inittially i had the time he was working but i just split the date with time.

```
df
    structure(list(user_id = c("6897bea62278", "6897bea62278", "13d51bc5b108", 
    "8012f20570b5", "5bc61ba43a08", "13d51bc5b108", "13d51bc5b108", 
    "6897bea62278", "8012f20570b5", "13d51bc5b108", "13d51bc5b108", 
    "6897bea62278", "13d51bc5b108", "13d51bc5b108", "8012f20570b5"
    ), date = structure(c(18687, 18687, 18687, 18687, 18687, 18687, 
     18687, 18687, 18687, 18687, 18687, 18687, 18687, 18687, 18687
    ), class = "Date")), row.names = c(2L, 4L, 8L, 16L, 18L, 20L, 
    23L, 27L, 39L, 40L, 41L, 43L, 45L, 51L, 55L), class = "data.frame")
```

desired output

for example in March all workers had an avg days of work 23 days

| Month | Avg days |
| --- | --- |
| March | 23 |
| April | 15 |

```
   avg_days<- df %>%
    group_by(month(Date)) %>%
    summarise(Avg_days =mean())
```

I am trying something like that... Any thoughts? Thank you

Comment: Can you update your post with expected output.  In the example `dput`, there is only a single unique date, so the average would be the same value as single observation

Comment: I uploaded the desired output. Every id has worked a lot of times during the day , so for that id that counts for just one day.  @akrun

Comment: sorry, it is not clear.  I get 15 for March based on your example `df %>% group_by(Month = format(as.Date(date), "%B")) %>% summarise(n = n())`

Comment: `avg_days <- df %>% distinct(user_id, date) %>% count(user_id, month = lubridate::floor_date(date)) %>% group_by(month) %>% summarize(avg_days = mean(n))`

Comment: @JonSpring it doesnt work properly to df. it is giving me all the unique values in date column and how many times there in the df , which is 1 for all of them. One other idea is to calculate the max dat - min date for every id and then calculate their mean. All this for every month!

Comment: @JonSpring yes excactly, so no matter how many times in the day I did tasks for my work, this counts  that I worked that day. In the end of the month I will have worked 20 days.  Another worker have worked 15 days, so we want this average for that specific month and every month. The tricky part is how many records of my id with same same date exists and they should not be included in the calculations but just one time only. Actually, I have a col with date and time and I convert it into POSIXct. Maybe if I use this column will make things easier, as it has unique values caused of h,m and sec